# Error using ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 in the Login Route of the Auth Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm getting a "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString'" Exception when initializing a new Saml2AuthnRequest object in the Login method of my Auth Controller.

[image]

Here is where I initialize the Saml2Configuration Object on project startup

```
using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web;

namespace OSUFeeTrackingWebApplication
{
    public class SAMLConfig
    {
        public static Saml2Configuration Config { get; private set; }

        public static string RelayStateReturnUrl { get; private set; }
      
        public static void ConfigureSAML()
        {
            Config = new Saml2Configuration();

            RelayStateReturnUrl = "relayStateReturnUrl";

            // Adding the Issuer URI (Our application) as an allowed audience for the SAML responses
            Config.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(Config.Issuer);

            // Set the SAML identity provider entity ID
            Config.AllowedIssuer = "https://login.oregonstate.edu/idp/shibboleth";

            // Set the SAML single sign-on endpoint URL (redirect binding)
            Config.SingleSignOnDestination = new Uri("https://login.oregonstate.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO");

            // Certificate used to sign outgoing SAML requests. We send the public key to the IdP with our SAML requests
            Config.SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate("path/to/signing/certificate");

            // Certificate used for validating the incoming SAML response from the IdP
            Config.SignatureValidationCertificates.Add(LoadCertificate("path/to/certificate"));

        }

        // Helper function to retrieve the certificate
        private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string path)
        {
            // Load the certificate from the specified path and password
            return new X509Certificate2(path);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the error is because the uriString field in my config object isn't initialized:

[image]

But I can't figure out why this line didn't initialize it correctly:

```
// Adding the Issuer URI (Our application) as an allowed audience for the SAML responses
            Config.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(Config.Issuer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out, turned out the Issuer property of my config object was null so once I set that the error went away.

Comment: Try to format the answer so that it is clear and helpful to others.  You can remove the preamble "Nevermind I figured..."